# Free way to store custom data for a google player account. (Android, GPGS)

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am looking for a way to store some simple data (game progress, unlocks, etc.) for my android-game. The game will make use of an ingame currency (earned via rewards, in-app-purchase, ad watching) thus storing data locally is no option.

The requirement are:

- Data should be persistant even if the user change the device, or uninstall the game.
- it should not be to easy to cheat
- i am looking for a free and easy way to implement this, with quotas big enough even if the game is a success

With those in mind, I thought I will be able to use the Google Play Games Services to achieve this.
But Saved Games cannot be the choice, because they will be uninstalled, if the user uninstall the game, and the requirement to have a icon do not fit my need.
I could use achievments to "store" which items the player unlocked/bought already, but i cannot manage the currency itselt with achievements.
I could use the billing api, if there would be an option to configure products as "buy with virtual-money only" and if it has a bank-account-option for virtual currency. (I really don't get it, why such features do not exist)

I still have a little hope, I find a way to misuse some of the free features around the google-player-account to store what I need.
Any tips for me?

If there is no way around to rent a cloud-db myown, any suggestions on that?

PS: excuse my english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to store your data. It is a backend that is provided by Google that includes a real-time database. It is free upto a certain limit. Failing that, there are also free third-party hosters like hostinger.com and 000webhost.com which offer free PHP and MySQL systems.

Comment: Thanks, I go with Firebase now. The only "drawback" so far, is that i need an additional GoogleApiClient for the Google Sign In.